# If $T\colon V\to V$ is linear then$\text{ Im}(T) = \ker(T)$ implies $T^2 = 0$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I'm trying to show that if $V$ is finite dimensional and $T\colon V\to V$ is linear then$\text{ Im}(T) = \ker(T)$ implies $T^2 = 0$.

I've tried taking a $v$ in the kernel and then since it's in the kernel we know its in the image so there is a $w$ such that $T(w) = v$, so then $TT(w) = 0$, but thats only for a specific $w$?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\text{For }v\in V,~Tv\in \text{im}(T)=\ker(T)\implies T(Tv)=0$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Note that $T^2$ should be read as $T\circ T$. You wish to show that $(\forall v\in V)((T\circ T)(v)=0)$. I think you can do this.

Comment: Got it thanks! I was being a bit stupid...

Comment: @Wooster No problem.

Answer (score 1):

For all $v$, $Tv$ is in the image of $T$, so it is in the kernel, then $T (Tv) = 0$ as required.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: $T^2=0$ iff $\operatorname{Im} T\subseteq \operatorname{ker} T$. And you don't even need $T$ to be linear.