# Proving that $Ker A = Im A$ if and only if $2rank(A)=n$ and $A^2=0$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A$ be an $n\times n$ matrix and we assume that $Ker A = Im A$.

We want to prove that $2rank(A)=n$ and that $\forall X \in R^n$, such that $A^2X=0$, it holds that $A^2=0$

How do I approach this question?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [If $T\colon V\to V$ is linear then$\text{ Im}(T) = \ker(T)$ implies $T^2 = 0$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/409259/if-t-colon-v-to-v-is-linear-then-text-imt-kert-implies-t2-0)

Comment: Use the [Rank-Nullity-Theorem](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/409259/if-t-colon-v-to-v-is-linear-then-text-imt-kert-implies-t2-0) to obtain $2\, {\rm rank}(A)=n$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde: The question that you link to asks only about half of the present question. It is then only a "half-duplicate".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first part follows from the rank-nullity theorem: viewing $ A $ as a linear map, we have $ \dim (\ker A) + \dim (\textrm{Im} A) = n $. If $ \ker A = \textrm{Im} A $, then their dimensions are equal, and the result follows immediately.

For the second part, note that for any vector $ v $ we have $ Av \in \textrm{Im} A $ by definition of image. However, since the image and the kernel coincide, we must have that $ Av \in \ker A $ or $ A(Av) = A^2 v = 0 $ for any vector $ v $. This is only possible iff $ A^2 = 0 $.

Answer (score 0):

If $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$, then $Ax \in \operatorname{Im}(A) = \operatorname{Ker}(A)$ and so $A(Ax) = (A^2)x = 0$. By taking $x = e_i$ (the standard basis vectors) or by the correspondence between matrices and linear maps, you can see that this implies that $A = 0$.

By the rank-nullity theorem,

$$ \dim \operatorname{Ker}(A) + \dim \operatorname{Im}(A) = 2 \dim \operatorname{Im}(A) = 2 \operatorname{rank}(A) = n. $$

Answer (score 0):

Most easy answer should be:

Let $v\in V ,\ w\in Ker(A)$ thus $\forall w \quad Aw=0$

Since $Im(A)=Ker(A)$ and $Av\in Im(A)$ follows $A(Av)=A(w)=0$ for all $v \in V$.
Thus $A*A=A^2=0$
$\quad\square$